# Apachae 10048 error

Tags: ports

Posted this elsewhere, since no reply yet, thought of posting here as well. I could not even start up my Apachae, so I ran the httpd.exe -e debug command from C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin

I got a message that says:
Only one usage of each socket adsress  is normally permitted. : make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 No listening sockets available, shutting down Unable to open logs.

So I changed it to port 81, this time it could start up, but I still get the same error when I run the above command. Meaning, this time the server is running but yet giving the same error message for the new port, which is port 81. I am not sure why this is happening. Hope someone can advise. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running Skype? There is a setting in Skype that is enabled by default that enables it to be used on Port 80. There is also a snippet floating around for checking what is actually using port 80. Ill edit this if I find it again

Comment: Hi Oberst, thanks for the quick response. Yeah I heard about Skype giving this problem, but in my machine, Skype is not installed.

Comment: Found it. In a CMD window, `netstat -ano` should give you a read out of the applications and the port they are using. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907980

Comment: Thanks Oberst, I ran the command and it return the result by saying that for port 80 and 81 the  foreign address is: 0.0.0.0.0 and the state is 'Listening' and it gave separate PID numbers for 80 and 81. I believe the PID numbers could be referring to the applications running on that port, if so, how do I find out which app is using those ports based on the these PID numbers?

Comment: You should be able to open up a task manager, switch to the processes tab, and sort by PID. But I believe netstat has a flag for displaying the program name (or at the least, its filename) too. EDIT: Ahh... I just checked my task manager. View > Select Columns... > Put a check in PID. ;)

Comment: Ah ha... `netstat -anob`. The b flag tells you what file owns that process. But it requires an elevated prompt. (Shouldn't be a problem though)